# How to add JPanel by clicking JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a small GUI, it has 2 JButtons, and 2 JPanels with some drawing animation on each of them. By default it must show first JPanel, and by clicking on second JButton I want to see my second JPanel. So : I create JFrame, Panel1 and Panel2, where I have drawn my animations, create Button1 and Button2 and adding to them ActionListeners. I have also MainPanel which has in a fields variable i. By changing this "i" my constructor adds to MainPanel either Panel1 (default) or Panel2 (by clicking on JButton2 I change i). Than I add this MainPanel to my frame. So my question : in the class MainPanel I have refreshMe method, what should I write there to make my GUI working properly? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        MainPanel myPanel = new MainPanel();
        f.add(myPanel);
        Button1 button1 = new Button1();
        Button2 button2 = new Button2();
        myPanel.add(button1);
        myPanel.add(button2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
    Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
    public int i = 1;  //this is being changed later by clicking JButton
    // I use this setter later in actionPerformed in order to change i
    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    MainPanel() { 
        if (i == 1) {
            this.add(p1);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            this.add(p2);
        }
    }

    public void refreshMe() {
        // Need some help here:
        // I don't know what should I write, how to make a repaint of myPanel?
        System.out.println("just test, if the method refreshMe working by clicking some button");
    }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // a lot of drawing stuff going on here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    public Panel2() {
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        // a lot of drawing stuff going on here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}

class Button1 extends JButton {
    MainPanel someObj1 = new MainPanel();

    Button1() {
        setText("Show Annimation A");
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                someObj1.setI(1);
                System.out.println("The variable i is now: " + someObj1.i);
                someObj1.refreshMe();

            }
        });
    }

}

class Button2 extends JButton {
    MainPanel someObj2 = new MainPanel();

    Button2() {
        setText("Show Annimation B");
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                someObj2.setI(2);
                System.out.println("The variable i is now: " + someObj2.i);
                someObj2.refreshMe();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to reflect changes after adding/removing or resizing a component that is on a visible container call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the containers instance after adding/removing or resizing the component.

Though this will not work in your code the main reason being inside JButton classes you recreate a new instance of `MainPanel` when in fact the 2 `JButtons` should share the single instance which is being used (you could pass MainPanel instance to the `JButton`s constructors, but you shouldn't really be extending a `JButton` unless adding custom functionality):

```
class Button2 extends JButton {
    MainPanel someObj2 = new MainPanel();//you create an instance of MainPanel which isnt even showing and than do changes on that, this way you will never see any of the changes

    Button2() {
    }
}
```

A few other suggestions on your code:

- Dont extend `JButton` class unnecessarily, simply create an instance of `JButton` like you did with `JFrame` and call methods on `JButton` instance.
- Dont forget to create/manipulate Swing components on `Event Dispatch Thread`, via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` block, read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more.

Here is your code fixed (above suggestions ect implemented):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();

                final MainPanel myPanel = new MainPanel();
                f.add(myPanel);

                JButton button1 = new JButton("Show Animation A");
                JButton button2 = new JButton("Show Animation B");

                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        myPanel.setI(1);
                        System.out.println("The variable i is now: " + myPanel.i);
                        myPanel.refreshMe();
                    }
                });
                button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        myPanel.setI(2);
                        System.out.println("The variable i is now: " + myPanel.i);
                        myPanel.refreshMe();
                    }
                });

                myPanel.add(button1);
                myPanel.add(button2);
                myPanel.checkPanel();

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
    Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
    public int i = 1;  //this is being changed later by clicking JButton
    // I use this setter later in actionPerformed in order to change i

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void refreshMe() {
        checkPanel();

        revalidate();
        repaint();
        // Need some help here:
        // I don't know what should I write, how to make a repaint of myPanel?
        System.out.println("just test, if the method refreshMe working by clicking some button");
    }

    public void checkPanel() {
        if (i == 1) {
            this.add(p1);
            this.remove(p2);//or it will remain there as this is default flowlayout
        } else if (i == 2) {
            this.add(p2);
            this.remove(p1);
        }
    }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // a lot of drawing stuff going on here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    public Panel2() {
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        // a lot of drawing stuff going on here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}
```

However Id suggest something simpler, fortunately you have 2 choices:

1) Use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will allow you to flip between multiple components on a single `JFrame`/container.

Here is an example I made:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private final static String PANEL1 = "panel 1";
    private final static String PANEL2 = "panel 2";

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Panel 1"));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Panel 2"));

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(panel1, PANEL1);
        cards.add(panel2, PANEL2);

        //create button to allow chnage to next card
        JButton buttonNext = new JButton(">");
        buttonNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());//get cards
                cl.next(cards);
            }
        });

        //create button to allow chnage to previous card
        JButton buttonPrev = new JButton("<");
        buttonPrev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());//get cards
                cl.previous(cards);
            }
        });

        //create panel to hold buttons which will allow switching between cards
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(buttonPrev);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonNext);


        frame.add(cards);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

2) Use `removeAll()` technique i.e call `frame.getContentPane().removeAll()` which will remove all components currently on `JFrame` and than add the new content and call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` (also might want to add `pack()` in there) on `JFrame` instance to reflect changes. Though Id recommend `CardLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code and  example, this helps a lot! Yes, CardLayout solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use `CardLayout` to implement your function. Please refer to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)