# How to properly hide a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jframe

I have a very simple `JFrame` window that contains one button: `No`.

In the main function I set `setVisible(true);` my `JFrame` and in the `No` button listener I want to close the window so I set the visibility to false: `setVisible(false);` and after that I do `System.exit(0);` in order to prevent possible memory leaks when running the program many times.

I have two questions:

1. Do I really need to `System.exit(0);` in the above case?
2. If I have this `JFrame` as a `popup` window, I can't really use `System.exit(0);` because this will terminate the whole program. So how can I properly close the popup window and stay in the main `JFrame` window? (Now I close it only by `setVisible(false);` and when I do it several times through the program execution, the program turns very slow).

Comment: you can use the function `dispose()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
2. if is there real reason for another popup container

   - use [`JDialog` with parent to `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), with [`setModal` / `ModalityTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29)
   - [create only one JDialog and to reuse this one `JDialog` by `getContentPane#removeAll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)
   - use `JOptionPane` for simple users interaction
3. put both together, above two points, to use `CardLayout` for popup `JDialog` with parent to `JFrame`, notice after switch from one card to another could be / is required to call `JDialog.pack()`

Comment: @MarounMaroun see here [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) and +1 mKorbel for cardlayout. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011397/how-to-add-jpanel-by-clicking-jbutton/14012757#14012757) for an example

Answer (score 4):

1. `setVisible` will cause slowdown
2. `dispose` will cause slowdown
3. `System.exit` will close entire JVM

Therefore, you should reuse a single `JFrame` or `JDialog`.

In the button's `ActionListener`, invoke `frame.setVisible(false);`. Then instead of creating a new frame just do `frame.setVisible(true);`. If you want to change the contents of the frame, there is the function `frame.getContentPane().removeAll();`.

Comment: hmmm even I upvote, now I see...., please to change `frame.removeAll();` to `frame.getContentPane().removeAll();` I saw a few time that you'll able to remove `RootPane` then there stays only translucent window with `Toolbar` with `Borders`, any contents, nothing else

Answer (score 3):

Just add this: `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.
Note: The default option for `JFrame` is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: This will cause the program to slow down much like `setVisible(false);`.

Comment: @Doorknob According to  `JFrame`'s doc( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int) ), `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`: Automatically hide and **dispose** the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects, which is different from `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: Dispose does not mean "free up resources." Try making a program that makes tons of `JFrame`s and disposes them, it will slow down a LOT.

Comment: @Doorknob *"Try making a program that makes tons of `JFrame`s"*  What number is 'tons'?  While I am not a huge fan of multiple frames, you would not notice a slow down from 100 frame instances (until you go to close them and realize that you need to close *each* of the 100!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dispose()` method of the `JFrame` class to close the frame and release all resources associated with it, including its child components.