# Can't receive keyboard input in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to get some basic keyboard input functionality like the arrow keys.
However, nothing i try seems to work, i've been using the KeyListener interface, the JPanel that checks for input gets the focus, and there seem to be no errors.

```
    public class PlayField extends JPanel implements KeyListener
    {
        private SpelModel mijnmodel;
        private boolean rechts = false;
        private boolean links = false;

        public PlayField(SpelModel mijnmodelArg)
        {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
            mijnmodel = mijnmodelArg;
            this.setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g); //some methods that i've taken out of the example
            drawStones(g,mijnmodel.getStenen());
            drawPeddle(g,mijnmodel.getBat());
            drawBall(g,mijnmodel.getBall()); 
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            System.out.println("Key Pressed!!!");           
    }

    //Called when the key is released   
        @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Released!!!");          
        }

        //Called when a key is typed
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
        }
```

Could the problem be that i am using multiple classes to create a window (first one JFrame, then one JPanel that includes 2 JPanels, whereof on is the "PlayField" class) and that the focus is impossible to achieve within another panel?
What is the best course of action?

Comment: It's been a while but I think you need to add key listeners to all the swing elements

Comment: @Will: nah, just use Key Bindings

Comment: @SnakesOnABoat, yeah, I'd never even heard of key bindings.  Been too long. (thank goodness)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key Listener doesn't work in a JFrame when traversing from another JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304711/key-listener-doesnt-work-in-a-jframe-when-traversing-from-another-jframe)

Answer (score 6):

Problems:

- You have a class that implements KeyListener, but I don't see you adding a KeyListener to any component. Implementing the interface is not enough, but instead the KeyListener must be added to a component to do listening.
- If you use KeyListeners, you must be careful with focus issues (as you've noted). The KeyListener only works if the component being listened to have focus.
- KeyListeners should be avoided with Swing applications, and you're better off using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). A brief search of this site will show you many discussions on this as this question has been asked and answered *many* times, more than several by me.
- For example: [java-keylistener-not-registering-arrow-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961998/522444)