# Refreshing JPanel to a new one

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

Is it possible to have a frame where by a new panel in that frame refreshes to the next panel, if you click the 2 link for example.

Is there easy code for this?

The picture below illustrates this better.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), this is what it's designed for.  It will allow you to switch out different components based on your needs

Check out [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more info

> Is there easy code for this?

That's a little subjective, but I would say `CardLayout` is the simplest of the possible solitons

Comment: @sansix if your up to an example, let me know and I'll up vote you ;) (on the iPad at the mo)

Comment: +1Mad... @user1992697 See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011397/how-to-add-jpanel-by-clicking-jbutton/14012757#14012757) example (at bottom of post) to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
            MainPanel.revalidate();
            MainPanel.add(SecondPanel);
            MainPanel.revalidate();
            firstPanel.setVisible(false);
            SecondPanel.setVisible(true);
            validate();
```

Comment: Why not simply `remove()` and `add()`?

Comment: This is more complicated than using a `CardLayout`.

Comment: There are also considerations to the layout manager. For example, BorderLayout won't allow two components to occupy the same position, and no amount of setVisible will correct it