# JFrame and different "pages" of content

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm quite new to Java, and right now I'm playing around with GUI. I now have a `JFrame` - lets call it `page1` - with a bit of content (text, images etc). So what I want to do is to create several such "pages" with different content, and be able to switch between these pages within my program.

So my question is, what's the best way to do this? Say I want to create a `page2` with different images and text, what should I be looking at to make that happen?

I hope this is somewhat understandable. I just need to be pushed in the right direction so I know what to dig into.

Comment: Look for `CardLayout` - If I understood your question, you'll understand my comment.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but since you mention pages, I'm guessing you want to create a wizard.  Take a look at Oracle's guide to wizards.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011397/how-to-add-jpanel-by-clicking-jbutton/14012757#14012757) example of CardLayout (near the bottom of the answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use `CardLayout` . Here is a tutorial [how to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Example :

```
//Where instance variables are declared:
JPanel cards;
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

//Where the components controlled by the CardLayout are initialized:
//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
...
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
...

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
```